# How to make Read more and Read less in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I want to show only 20 characters by default after a click on Read more button full content should be visible.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Card from "../pages/Card";
import Servicesdata from "../data/Servicesdata";

const Services = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <section className="services">
        <div className="container mt-5">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <h2 className="text-center heading-style-1">Key Areas</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          {Servicesdata.map((val, index) => {
            return (
              <Card
                key={index}
                title={val.title}
                desc={val.desc}
                img={val.imgsrc}
                newSrc={val.newSrc}
                id={index}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default Services;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
const Servicesdata = [
  {
    ID: "01",
    title: "Power Generation",
    desc:
      " We have rich experience in building thermal, hydro, and combined cycle power plants. We provide customized ready-to-deploy solutions for power plants including total EPC and comprehensive Balance of Plant (BOP) and Flue-gas desulfurization (FGD) solutions.",
    imgsrc: "https://www.tataprojects.com/images/Transmission-Line.jpg",
    newSrc: "https://www.tataprojects.com/images/Transmission-Line.jpg"
  },

  {
    ID: "02",
    title: "Transmission",
    desc:
      "We have successfully commissioned more than 13,000 kms of transmission lines across multiple voltage levels including 800kv HVDC projects",
    imgsrc: "https://www.tataprojects.com/images/Sunbstations-min.jpg",
    newSrc: "https://www.tataprojects.com/images/Transmission-Line.jpg"
  },
  {
    ID: "03",
    title: "Substations",
    desc:
      "Our optimally designed towers and substation structures allow us to reduce conductor wastage ensuring faster construction and on-time delivery.",
    imgsrc: "https://www.tataprojects.com/images/Tower-Manufactaring-Unit.jpg",
    newSrc: "https://www.tataprojects.com/images/Transmission-Line.jpg"
  },

  {
    ID: "04",
    title: "Tower Manufacturing Unit",
    desc:
      "We have a state-of-the-art manufacturing unit to manufacture transmission line towers and structures. The unit is spread across 40 acres of land.",
    imgsrc: "https://www.tataprojects.com/images/Smart-Grid-min.jpg",
    newSrc: "https://www.tataprojects.com/images/Transmission-Line.jpg"
  }
];

export default Servicesdata;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Card = props => {
  //Store the currently hovered object's id in the state
  //Initially it'll be ""
  const [currentHoveredId, setCurrentHoveredId] = useState("");

  //On mouse over update the id with the cuurent object's ID
  const onMouseOver = id => {
    setCurrentHoveredId(id);
  };

  //On moving the cursoe out of the image, then reset it to ""
  const onMouseOut = () => {
    setCurrentHoveredId("");
  };

  return (
    <>
      {props.id % 2 !== 0 ? (
        <div className="row featurette align-items-center">
          <div className="col-md-7">
            <h2 className="featurette-heading">{props.title}</h2>
            <p className="lead">{props.desc}</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-5">
            <img
              src={currentHoveredId === props.id ? props.newSrc : props.img}
              className={`${
                currentHoveredId === props.id ? "fadeInLeft" : "fadeInRight"
              } img-fluid`}
              onMouseOver={() => {
                onMouseOver(props.id);
              }}
              onMouseOut={onMouseOut}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : null}

      {props.id % 2 === 0 ? (
        <div className="row featurette align-items-center">
          <div className="col-md-5">
            <img
              src={currentHoveredId === props.id ? props.newSrc : props.img}
              className={`${
                currentHoveredId === props.id ? "fadeInRight" : "fadeInLeft"
              } img-fluid`}
              onMouseOver={() => {
                onMouseOver(props.id);
              }}
              onMouseOut={onMouseOut}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="col-md-7">
            <h2 className="featurette-heading">{props.title}</h2>
            <p className="lead">{props.desc}</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Comment: This question contains 143 lines of code and the Lorem Ipsum text... just to ask how a portion of text can be hidden. This is way to much. It is a code dump. Please spend the time and care to trim this down to a concise and clear question.

Comment: I have added clearly my question and description still showing below message while submitting, therefore i have added Lorem Ipssum

message:
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: You are supposed to only post the code that is necessairy to ask a clear question. Not the entire code of your component or your app. And adding random text like wikipedia entries (as you have done in another question) or just duplicating you question text is not going to raise the quality of your question, it lowers it drastically. Please trim down the code. This would also be good advice for your other questions and for future questions.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a new state into your Card Component to control what to show.

```
const [showFullDescription, setFullDescription] = useState(false);
```

Then in your button you can toggle between show full text or not.

```
const showFullDescriptionHandler = () => {
    setFullDescription(!showFullDescription);
  };

const description = showFullDescription
    ? props.desc
    : props.desc.slice(0, 20);

<div className="col-md-7">
    <h2 className="featurette-heading">{props.title}</h2>
    <p className="lead">{description}</p>
    <button onClick={showFullDescriptionHandler}>
        Read {showFullDescription ? "Less" : "More"}
     </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that works great in nextjs thx alot

Answer (score 0):

This function will do

```
function truncateString(str, num) {
  // If the length of str is less than or equal to num
  // just return str--don't truncate it.
  if (str.length <= num) {
    return str
  }
  // Return str truncated with '...' concatenated to the end of str.
  return str.slice(0, num) + '...'
}

truncateString("A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket", 8);
```

It's an extract from this post [https://medium.com/@DylanAttal/truncate-a-string-in-javascript-41f33171d5a8](truncation in Javascipt)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a component that accepts HTML elements (as react elements) and not just strings, and then truncates the final text to be displayed according to a limit you specify, you can parse the input, access the children of the elements until you reach a string, then count the amount of chars in the string, truncating and stopping the process after the maximum amount of chars is reached.

The following is an example of a component to do that:

```tsx
import React from 'react';

type ParseResult = {
    content: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[];
    remaining: number;
};

type Parse = (root: ParseResult, parse: Parse) => ParseResult;

const parseString = (text: string, remaining: number): ParseResult => {
    if (!text?.length) {
        return { content: text, remaining };
    }

    const newText =
        remaining <= 0
            ? ''
            : text.length > remaining
            ? text.substring(0, remaining)
            : text;

    return { content: newText, remaining: remaining - text.length };
};

const parse: Parse = (root, parseCallback) => {
    const { content, remaining = 0 } = root;

    if (typeof content === 'string') {
        const result = parseString(content, remaining);
        return result;
    } else if (React.isValidElement(content)) {
        const children = (content.props as { children?: React.ReactNode })
            ?.children;

        if (children != null) {
            const innerResult = parseCallback(
                {
                    content: children,
                    remaining,
                },
                parseCallback,
            );
            const newContent = React.cloneElement(content, {}, innerResult.content);
            return { content: newContent, remaining: innerResult.remaining };
        }
    } else if (Array.isArray(content)) {
        const list: React.ReactNode[] = [];
        let newRemaining = remaining;

        for (const child of content) {
            const parsed = parseCallback(
                { content: child, remaining: newRemaining },
                parseCallback,
            );
            newRemaining = parsed.remaining;
            const newContent = (
                <React.Fragment key={list.length}>{parsed.content}</React.Fragment>
            );
            list.push(newContent);

            if (newRemaining < 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        return { content: list, remaining: newRemaining };
    }

    return root;
};

export interface ReadMoreAdditionalProps {
    expanded?: boolean;
    showMore?: React.ReactNode;
    showLess?: React.ReactNode;
}

const ReadMoreInner: React.FC<
    {
        children: React.ReactNode;
        truncate: number;
    } & ReadMoreAdditionalProps
> = ({ truncate, expanded, showMore, showLess, children }) => {
    const root: ParseResult = {
        content: children,
        remaining: truncate,
    };
    const result = parse(root, parse);

    return (
        <>
            {expanded ? children : result.content}
            {result.remaining < 0 ? (expanded ? showLess : showMore) : undefined}
        </>
    );
};

export interface ReadMoreOptions extends ReadMoreAdditionalProps {
    truncate?: number;
}

export type ReadMoreProps = ReadMoreOptions & {
    children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const ReadMore: React.FC<ReadMoreProps> = ({
    truncate,
    children,
    ...props
}) => {
    return truncate != null ? (
        <ReadMoreInner {...props} truncate={truncate}>
            {children}
        </ReadMoreInner>
    ) : (
        <>{children}</>
    );
};
```

Keep in mind that this component expects the children components to contain the final text (or no text). It won't access other properties (like a `text` or `title` property), but that should be fine for HTML components.

The above component itself is not bound by HTML and require no other libraries than react, so it can be used in react native too.

You can just include this component in your code, add buttons to show more or less text and then style the buttons the way you want.

I created a library to do this and an easily customizable web component if you prefer to not add all the component code in your project.

Install the library with:

```tsx
npm install react-shorten
```

Below is an example of how to use the library:

```tsx
import { ReadMoreWeb } from 'react-shorten';
import React from 'react';

const StyledReadMore: React.FC<{
    truncate?: number;
    children: React.ReactNode;
}> = ({ truncate, children }) => (
    <ReadMoreWeb
        truncate={100}
        showMoreText="Show more"
        showLessText="Show less"
        className="read-more-btn"
    >
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed
        ullamcorper, odio eu aliquam ultricies, enim sapien aliquet arcu, quis
        aliquam diam massa eu nisl. Sed vitae nunc eget nunc ullamcorper
        aliquet. Sed euismod, nisl eget aliquam ultricies, justo nisl aliquet
        nunc, quis aliquam diam massa eu nisl. Sed vitae nunc eget nunc
        ullamcorper aliquet. Sed euismod, nisl eget aliquam ultricies, justo
        nisl aliquet nunc, quis aliquam diam massa eu nisl. Sed vitae nunc eget
        nunc ullamcorper aliquet.
    </ReadMoreWeb>
);
```

with the css:

```css
.read-more-btn {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: rgb(80, 154, 223);
    background: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.link {
    color: rgb(26, 210, 243);
}
```

You can see a web demo [here](https://lucasbasquerotto.github.io/react-read-more/) and a native demo [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@lucasbasquerotto/react-shorten).

You can also use the demos as references and include the [ReadMore](https://github.com/lucasbasquerotto/react-read-more/blob/main/src/components/read-more.tsx) and [ReadMoreWeb](https://github.com/lucasbasquerotto/react-read-more/blob/main/src/components/read-more-web.tsx) components directly in your project, if you prefer to not install another library.